# MySQL making 6.5m row update filter through without errors

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

I am running said query:

```
UPDATE `tbl_audit_trail` 
   SET model = CONCAT('common\\models\\', model) 
 WHERE model NOT LIKE 'common\\\\models%'
```

to update 6,567,780 records.

The current details are:

- Table size 1.6GB
- The engine is InnoDB
- Linux 2.6
- MySQL server 5.1.63-0+squeeze1-log

This results in said error:

```
The table 'tbl_audit_trail' is full
```

After reading the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/full-table.html I thought it might have been temp_table problems but it says that such problems should only effect people on older than 3.23.

What could be stopping my query from running?

Comment: Have you tried select into another table?

Comment: @Alexander I have not yet since it is 6m rows, it seems like a bad idea to place such IO on the server

Comment: @Alexander you mean by basically taking the rows and placing them in a new table right?

Comment: YEs, that's what I meant. You can use `CASE` to selectively change this `model` column

Comment: You might want to try doing the updates one at a time using a cursor inside a stored routine.

Comment: @TimBurch would batches work?

Comment: Batches would be less likely to trigger the error you're experiencing, I think. If you're working on a live application, you should definitely do what you can to avoid updating millions of records at once, because an update of that size is likely to have a negative impact on performance, even if it doesn't trigger the error you experienced.

Comment: @TimBurch indeed I have taken precautions to make sure that the priority of this update is lowered so that all other operations take over if needed etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did truly find out the reason however, I batched the update, omitting the single commit of all 6m rows (which loses atomicity of the update) and it worked.

It does seem as though there was something attached to updating that caused it to crash and batching the updates to about 100,000 at a time worked, even if the next update was done straight after the previous giving the server no rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Reasons this might happen :**

- Check that the disk the InnoDB data file is stored on isn't full
- Check your `innodb_data_file_path` variable form you my.cnf

For a complete troubleshoot here is an [post from Rolando](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table) - this will defensively do it !

Comment: Hmm it could be the logs, commiting only once at the end of the transaction could do the trick

Comment: it could ! if you can do that! -- but this innodb problem is so complex, because of the engine complexity - there could be so many points of error !